# Invalid Azure Document DB Request Charges for Read Operation

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using .Net Azure Document DB SDK.

Reading 2500 documents using ExecuteNextAsync(), in FeedRespons result it shows 800 Request Charges but my collection has only 400 RU's and Fixed size assigned.

Document size is less than 0.5 KB.

Getting all 2500 documents in **single call**, so request charges calculated on which basis? I am expecting it less than **400 RU's**, as my collection has 400 RU's assigned.

Comment: RU budget has nothing to do with the cost of operations. And if you exceed your budgeted allocation of Request Units per second, the operation will complete, but then you'll be unable to run any more queries until the RU deficit is rectified (e.g. if you burn 800 RU in a single operation, you'll be throttled until somewhere around 2 seconds elapses). Also: the cost of your search isn't tied to the size of your document; it's mainly the query itself. Anyway... this is unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow. You can find plenty of documentation around Request Units, throttling, etc.

Comment: Also - your question title is misleading: there's nothing invalid about your Request Unit charges. Just that you're making a false assertion about what RU's are, and what their limits are.

Comment: Hi  @DavidMakogon , Actually i created console application to test read performance and i hosted it in azure in same region as my Document DB. To fetch 1000 document (select * from c) it take 1533 milliseconds(calculated by stop watch) and Request charges is 3274.72. As i configures 1000 RU/second, so how it utilize 3274 RUs for 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. Are you questioning how you could have consumed 3274 RU's in 1.5 seconds? If so, I already explained this in my first comment. Your query's cost (RU) has nothing to do with how much RU is allocated for your collection. If your query costs 3274 RU, it will cost 3274 RU if you have 400 RU 
 or 10,000 RU allocated. And it will take the same amount of time. And if you don't have enough RU (per second) to cover the cost, then you're throttled until things balance out again. (this is all well-documented - look up throttling in Cosmos DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Devid comment - 
Document DB query's cost (RU) has nothing to do with how much RU is allocated for your collection. If your query costs 3274 RU, it will cost 3274 RU if you have 400 RU or 10,000 RU allocated. And it will take the same amount of time. And if you don't have enough RU (per second) to cover the cost, then you're throttled until things balance out again.